# Specified argument was out of the range of valid value to get data from network in c#

Tags: c#, sockets, buffer, streamwriter

I am trying to send a command to a sensor and get the data from it using this code :

```
 const int PORT_NO = 3000;
        const string SERVER_IP = "192.168.2.44";


            //---listen at the specified IP and port no.---
            IPAddress localAdd = IPAddress.Any;
            TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(localAdd, PORT_NO);
            Console.WriteLine("Listening...");
            listener.Start();

            //---incoming client connected---
            TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
            NetworkStream nwStream = client.GetStream();

            //---write back the text to the client---
            byte[] buffersend = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];

            buffersend = GetBytes("00010002000B0300010004C380");
            int bytesSend = nwStream.Read(buffersend, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);

           // Console.WriteLine("Sending back : " + dataReceived);
            nwStream.Write(buffersend, 0, bytesSend);

            //---get the incoming data through a network stream---
            byte[] buffer = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];

            //---read incoming stream---
            int bytesRead = nwStream.Read(buffer, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);

            //---convert the data received into a string---
            string dataReceived = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            Console.WriteLine("Received : " + dataReceived);


            client.Close();
            listener.Stop();
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
```

in this line `int bytesSend = nwStream.Read(buffersend, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);` i got this error :

```
Specified argument was out of the range of valid value
```

the `buffersend` is 52 and the `client.ReceiveBufferSize` is 8192

```
static byte[] GetBytes(string str)
        {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[str.Length * sizeof(char)];
            System.Buffer.BlockCopy(str.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            return bytes;
        }
```

I am so new in c# socket programming

Comment: What does `GetBytes` do?  You might want to change `client.ReceiveBufferSize` to `buffersend.Length` to make sure you are not requesting more bytes then your buffer can hold.

Comment: @juharr it converts string to byte

Comment: Shouldn't `buffersend` only be used with the `Write`?  Why are you trying to read bytes into it after you populate it with bytes?  I'm just guessing, but I think you can just remove that first `Write` completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this

```
byte[] buffersend = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
buffersend = GetBytes("00010002000B0300010004C380");
int bytesSend = nwStream.Read(buffersend, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);
nwStream.Write(buffersend, 0, bytesSend);
```

I think you just want this.

```
byte[] buffersend =  GetBytes("00010002000B0300010004C380");
nwStream.Write(buffersend, 0, buffersend.Length);
```

There is no need to new up an array just to replace it with the results of `GetBytes`.  Also I do not think you want to read into `buffersend`, you just want to write it.  Your latter code will then read into `buffer`.

The reason you are getting the exception is that `buffersend` has a length that is less than `client.ReceiveBufferSize` per the documentation for [`NetworkStream.Read`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.read(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: what should i used instead bytesSend?

Comment: @EhsanAkbar Just replace that with `buffersend.Length`.

Comment: Thank you dear friend but i don't receive any data from the sensor ?!!!i Used herculas  and it works

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30972406/streamread-cant-read-any-data-from-networkstream-in-c-sharp